# how to solve, $(x^2-2x+2y^2)dx+2xydy=0$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

solve the following differential equation.

$\tag 1(x^2-2x+2y^2)\,dx+2xy\,dy=0$

$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{2x-x^2-2y^2}{2xy}$

dividing (1) throughout by $y^2$ we have,

$\tag 2 \left(\frac{x^2}{y^2}+2-2\frac{x}{y^2}\right)dx+2(\frac{x}{y})dy=0$

Comment: You can use the `\tag` command to tag equations.

Comment: What does equation (1) mean? the LHS is a non-zero 1-form, and the RHS is $0$!

Comment: There must be some typos in the formulas.

Comment: Multiply  equation $(1)$ by $x$. This will yield an exact differential equation. The method [here](http://www.cliffsnotes.com/study_guide/Integrating-Factors.topicArticleId-19736,articleId-19711.html) was used to find the integrating factor $x$.

Comment: @Julien a 1-form $\omega=a(x,y)dx+b(x,y)dy$ is zero iff $a=b=0$.

Comment: @Mercy Ah, yes, you're right! (+1 for your two comments). This question is not properly stated. It is not a differential equation. It should be: find $F(x,y)$ constant on $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $dF=(x^2-2x+2y^2)dx+2xydy$. Right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Illustrating @DavidMitra's idea: multiply through by $x$:

$$(x^3-2x^2+2xy^2)\,dx+2x^2y\,dy=0$$

We want to find a function $F(x,y)$ such that

$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial x} = x^3-2x^2+2xy^2$$

$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial y} = 2x^2y$$

From the former equation, we integrate with respect to $x$ and get

$$F(x,y) = \frac{1}{4} x^4 - \frac{2}{3} x^3 + x^2 y^2 + g(y)$$

From the latter, integrate with respect to $y$ and get:

$$F(x,y) = x^2 y^2 + f(x)$$

Comparing the two equations, we see that $f(x) = \frac{1}{4} x^4 - \frac{2}{3} x^3 $ and $g(y)=0$.  Therefore

$$F(x,y) = \frac{1}{4} x^4 - \frac{2}{3} x^3 + x^2 y^2$$

Solutions of your differential equation satisfy $F(x,y) = C$, a constant.

Comment: Perfect, +1. In view of @Mecy's comments, do you think we can really call this a differential equation? As is the question properly stated?

Comment: Sure, why not?  Divide through by $dx$ and you can see it easier.  What I showed is a standard technique, where $F$ is known as the first integral of the equation.  http://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/First_integral

Comment: Because what is given is a differential $1$-form. Dividing by $dx$ does not make sense in this context. And, as far as I know, you don't divide differential forms. Like @Mercy says, such an object is zero if and only if its coordinates are both zero, which leads to a system of equations which have nothing to do with differential equations (well, they're order zero diff eq, ok).

Comment: Dividing by $dx$ never really makes sense in any context, but it is a convenient mnemonic.  In this case, it reveals the equivalent diff eq'n.  Think about solving that diff eq'n: you would "multiply" by "$dx$ and integrate both sides to reveal something hopefully integrable.  What I showed here merely systemizes this.

Comment: Ok, well, we can't agree on everything. In my view, the question is not stated properly...

Answer (score 6):

Note:

In view of @Mercy's comments, I interpret your question as: find all constant functions $F(x,y)$ such that
$$
dF=(x^2-2x+2y^2)dx+2xydy.
$$

Nervertheless, I think you maybe meant your question to be: solve the ODE
$$
x^2-2x+2y^2+2xyy'=0.
$$

Setting $z=y^2$, we have $z'=2yy'$ so the equation becomes
$$
xz'+2z=2x-x^2.
$$
This is linear of first order.

A general method for solving this is the integrating factor method: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrating_factor.

As pointed out by David Mitra, in this case, this is very easy since this leads to
$$
x^2z'+2xz=2x^2-x^3\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad (x^2z)'=2x^2-x^3.
$$

Then integrate the latter.

Once you have $z$, take $\pm\sqrt{z}$ where it is nonnegative to find $y$.